# Calculate mean and stdev between similar formatted csv files and output to another file following format

Tags: csv

I have a group of output csv files from replicates of a simulation. Each file line in the file follow the same format: generation, number, value1, value2, .... valueX. (the file also include a header, same order.

I would like to calculate the mean and stdev between each cell of each file, and to output another csv file, where the mean would be in the same cell/position of the original files. The stdev can be in either another file in the same cell/position, or after all cells:

generation, number_mean, value1_mean, value2_mean,..., valueX_mean, value1_stdev, value2_stdev,...,valueX_stdev

What would be a good way to do this?

It is important that the output csv file follow the same format as the input files.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try the solution of my answer? Does it work?

Comment: Hey @aborruso, no, I haven't tried it yet. I ended up putting it to the side for now, going for a different approach at the moment, but I will revisit this later on. Thanks for checking back.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller).

In example starting from

```
a,v1,v2,v3
a,25,56,23
b,58,56,23
```

you can run [`merge-fields`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/index.html#merge-fields)

```
mlr --csv merge-fields -a mean,stddev -r "v[0-9]" -o "result" -k input.csv >output.csv
```

to have

| a | v1 | v2 | v3 | result_mean | result_stddev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 25 | 56 | 23 | 34.666667 | 18.502252 |
| b | 58 | 56 | 23 | 45.666667 | 19.655364 |